# Unknown Python Selenium error:Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\pythonProject\webscraping.py", line 17, in <module>

Tags: python, selenium, tqdm

I am making this little program for Minecraft as a little program for fun and practicing python. I am using selenium and when I was trying to get the name of something in the HTML webpage with find_element it gave me this massive error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonProject\webscraping.py", line 17, in <module>
    username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee; color:#3CE6E6')
  File "C:\Users\Han\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1253, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Han\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Han\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee; color:#3CE6E6"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.53)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00DB56B3+2184883]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D4E5F1+1762801]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C63DA8+802216]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C91B40+990016]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C91DDB+990683]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CBEC32+1174578]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CACB54+1100628]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CBCF52+1167186]
    Ordinal0 [0x00CAC926+1100070]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C86EA0+945824]
    Ordinal0 [0x00C87D96+949654]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01054192+2704034]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0104687D+2648461]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E4119A+529066]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E40006+524566]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D54F2B+1789739]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D59978+1808760]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D59A65+1808997]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D62A01+1845761]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x74F1FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77097A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77097A6E+238]
```

Here is my code for the program:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

x=Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=x)

pbar = tqdm(range(10))

for i in pbar:
    time.sleep(0.3)
    pbar.set_description("loading program")
PlankeName = input("Whos Planke Page would you like to view? ")
UserPlankeLink = "https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/" + PlankeName
driver.get(UserPlankeLink)

username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee; color:#3CE6E6')
print(username)
print("You are currently Viewing " + driver.title)
```

Please help!

Comment: The clue is in the error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee; color:#3CE6E6"]"}`   - that's the line that's failing, because it can't find your element.  Verify it exists. Verify it's by name - and wait for it too: add this once after you create driver: `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`  and see if it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is `NoSuchElementException` because your element is not found. This exists because your identifier is wrong, or the page has not fully loaded yet.

I've had a look at your page - and your identifier is wrong. But - It's also a poorly described website so it's a tricky one for beginners.

I updated it to use this xpath:

```
//div[h3[text()='Player Information']]//span[text()]
```

That is: From the `div`, which has the `h3` inside it and where that `h3` has text=player information - Get the span which has any text.

Using this this code:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # note i modified this to my driver - reset to yours
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

PlankeName = input("Whos Planke Page would you like to view? ")
UserPlankeLink = "https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/" + PlankeName
driver.get(UserPlankeLink)

username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[h3[text()='Player Information']]//span[text()]")
print(username.text)
print("You are currently Viewing " + driver.title)
```

When entering the input `test`  as the players name,  I get output:

```
You are currently Viewing Test's Stats | Plancke
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the username of the person from the webpage. The code currently gives the session and element ID

Comment: @HanTang - use `print(username.text)`  - if you want something specific please be ensure it's in the question.   Your error was because of the bad identifier - i fixed the problem with your code but had no idea you wanted the uesrname. I've updated the answer with the additional request